# Why "segmentation fault" by php -v

Tags: segmentation-fault, apache2

Why do I get a "segmentation fault" when I run the command "php -v"?

[image]

Thanks for help.

gondor(..)

Comment: Where does it say that a segfault occurred?

Comment: You are right, but why comes the hint?

Comment: What hint? And if there's no segfault, what's the question about?

Comment: Every time when I run a script "php abc.php" it comes the hint "Speicherzugriffsfehler"